# After published status from ubuntu store, how many days it takes to available the snap package in ubuntu store

Tags: 16.04, snap, upload, ubuntu-store

I was uploaded a snap package (simple "hello world" code) in private mode on last week.After the review my package has published. But i am searching in Ubuntu store , i can't find the package which i uploaded. Please someone tell me how many days Ubuntu takes to make the package available in the Ubuntu store or please tell me how to find the uploaded package.

Comment: If it's private, it will not appear on a plan `$ snap find`. Can you please tell us how are you searching for it?

Comment: I was searched in Ubuntu store and $ snap find.. But i really don't know how to search. If you know please tell me.